# HTML5/Canvas/Javascript - drawing shadows on overlapping lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm attempting to draw one line with a shadow, however when that line overlaps a different part of the same line the shadow seems to only appear underneath the entire line.

Ideally I'd like to draw the lines then apply styling (including shadows afterwards) however since I'm new to canvas I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ncdpn0um/

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="600" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var points = [];
points.push({
    x:50,
    y:50
});
points.push({
    x:350,
    y:50
});
points.push({
    x:550,
    y:300
});
points.push({
    x:700,
    y:50
});
points.push({
    x:50,
    y:300
});
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
for (i = 1; i < points.length; i ++) {
    ctx.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
}
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.8)";
ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
ctx.lineWidth = 50;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.lineWidth = 48;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.stroke();
</script>
```

Comment: To get the shadow to behave like you want, you will need to alternate drawing the shadow, then the line segment, then the shadow for the next line segment, then the segment itself, etc. Think of drawing in layers - the stuff you draw last is always going to be on the top.

Comment: that makes sense! thx, still new to canvas

Comment: ...and to add to @MaximillianLaumeister's good comment: You can use `shadowOffsetX` to draw the line itself off-canvas (it won't appear) but the offset will cause just the shadow to be drawn on-canvas.

Comment: The problem with drawing segments will be that the shadow has transparent areas and in the overlap between the segments the alpha channel will be mixed creating a dark "spot" between each segment. It's actually a bit more complicated to achieve what OP asks here..